# How to retrieve data from 2 column in one table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named accessories_other in my database. In the table, I have column :

1) Item 
2)Available

This is the illustration on how the data in the respective column.

### Item

Mouse

Keyboard

Cable

### Available

4

6

3

The thing is, I would like to select Item = 'Mouse' together with column 'Available'=4. If the available mouse is less than 5, it will send me an email for the next step. But I stuck until this stage.

This is SQL statement that I create, and it count each row for 'Available' column, and send the email if the row of Available column is less than 5, which is not I want.

```
$sql ="SELECT Item, Available FROM accessories_other WHERE Item ='Mouse' 
AND Available <5";
```

How do I do so that it can retrieve mouse which is the availability less than 5.

Comment: How is the Item table linked to the Available table

Comment: your query is correcto gringo..wats the problemo ?

Comment: @Linger Both Item and Available is in the same table. I just want to retrieve one row in Item which is Mouse and the number of mouse available. If the number of mouse is less than 5, then it will proceed to next step. Do you have any idea to do that ?

Comment: @mhasan The problem using the query above is, it also send email when I put the number of mouse is more than 5. I suspect it read all row in available column, not the number of mouse available only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is just to show how it could be done . You should be using MySQLi
>   or PDO . Also if in Production environment , you should not be
>   displaying MySQL errors to the user .

You could do it either way :

```
//  SQL to find Available value for Item Mouse
$sql = "SELECT Item, Available FROM accessories_other
        WHERE Item = 'Mouse'";
$result = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( 'Query failed.'.mysql_error() );
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ;
if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 )
{
    echo $row['Item'] ,': ' ,$row['Available'];
    if( $row['Available'] < 5 )
    {
    //  Code to send email
    }
    else
    {
    //  Code to what ever you would like to do here 
    }
}
```

or

```
//  SQL to find Available value for Item Mouse if it is less than 5
$sql = "SELECT Item, Available FROM accessories_other
        WHERE Item = 'Mouse' AND Available < 5";
$result = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( 'Query failed.'.mysql_error() );
if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 )
{
    //  Code to what ever you would like to do here
}
else
{
    echo $row['Item'] ,': ' ,$row['Available'];
    //  Code to send email
}
```

Comment: How can I do so that the query only display for Mouse. Excluding the Cable ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already try to figure it using this code below : SELECT Available FROM accessories_other WHERE Item ='Mouse' 
AND Available <5. It display Available, 4 as stated here. 

The only problem is, the output still say that mouse is >5 even in database was 4. 
'$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed.'.mysql_error());
$message ="msg here";
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
 {
 $Available = $row['Available'];       
 } 
  if($result< 5)
 require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
  else
 echo"blabla";'

Comment: Your answer really help me ! The problem is solve now. I use the first code and it works, thankfully. Thanks to you. I'll mark this as an answer to my question. Greets !

Answer (score 0):

I think your query will not show results of mouse which is lesser than 5..
I suggest you try:

```
$sql ="SELECT Item, Available FROM accessories_other WHERE Item ='Mouse';
```

and then, try to implement your code in another language..
if I'm not mistaken, you're using php..

Answer (score 0):

your query should return exactly one row if you have data in table "accessories" as shown here. unless you have duplicates like multiple rows rows with Item = 'Mouse' and same or different value which is also less than 5 then only query will return multiple results.
also just notice that in the explanation you use the table "accessories" but in sample query you have used table "accessories_other". make sure you are working against the right table.

[image]